# How to get values of map passed form apex to lwc js?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, collection

Apex code:

```
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Map<String,List<String>> getSeatList(id seatId, List<String> fieldSetList) {
    
    Map<String,List<String>> fieldMap = new Map<String,List<String>>();
    
    
    for(String fieldset : fieldSetList){
        List<String> tempList= new List<String>();
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : SeatsController.getFields(fieldset)) {
           tempList.add(f.getFieldPath());
        }
        fieldMap.put(fieldset,tempList);
    }
    System.debug('FieldMap'+fieldMap);
    return fieldMap;
   
    
}
```

LWC js:`

```
    @wire(accFieldSet, { seatId: '$seatId', fieldSetList : '$fieldSetList' })
wiredSeatList({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        console.log('@@'+Object.keys(data))
        this.variable1 = ???

       
    } else if (error) {
       
        
    }
}
```

How to get value from map and assign to variables in lwc js?

1st variable = 1st value related to the first key element in map
2nd variable = 2nd value related to the second key element in map

Comment: If you just need the values then you can create an apex class wrapper and return a list of wrappers from the apex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should add the elements to a `list` or `map` and manipulate the `list` or `map` to achieve your desired output, instead of having separate variables

For pushing the data to a map you can use the below code,

```
@track mapData = [];
@wire(accFieldSet, {seatId: '$seatId',fieldSetList: '$fieldSetList'})
wiredSeatList({error,data}) {
    if (data) {
        for (let key in data) {
           this.mapData.push({value:data[key], key:key});
        }
    } else if (error) {
        window.console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Then in the `html` you can access something like this,

```
<template for:each={mapData} for:item="keyValue">
    <tr key={keyValue.key}>
        <th scope="col">
            <div>{keyValue.key}</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            <div>{keyValue.value}</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</template>
```

But still, if want to set it as per your variable, I would say to try out the below **not a best** approach, where you can have a counter and use the value   check and set variable accordingly

```
let count = 0;
@wire(accFieldSet, {seatId: '$seatId',fieldSetList: '$fieldSetList'})
wiredSeatList({error,data}) {
    if (data) {
        for (let key in data) {
            count++;
            if(count==1) {
                this.variable1 = data[key];
            }
            else if(count==2) {
                this.variable2 = data[key];
            }
        }
    } else if (error) {
        window.console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to put it in map only . 
let myMap = new Map();
            for (let key in data) {
                myMap.set(key,data[key]);
}
but not able to access value of map as myMap.get('Test'). It says undefined.

Comment: Updated the answer to set `mapData`